# Alternate method for dojo.xhrGet() method

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am new to Dojo Framework.I created one button using dojo constructor and dojo.connect onclick event function i written url and load functions.This url navigating servlet and get the response back.

but i don't want response back i want to send request only.

how to do this..anyone help me.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

are you looking to navigate to another page? if so, you can use window.location.href or other approaches to achieve that. See the foll url for other approaches:

[JavaScript: Navigate to a new URL without replacing the current page in the history (not window.location)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328283/javascript-navigate-to-a-new-url-without-replacing-the-current-page-in-the-hist)

if you do not want to navigate but just send some data to the server (and dont care about the response), you can just write an empty function for the callback

```
var deferred = dojo.xhrGet( {
    url : "xxx",
    load: function(data) {
          //ignore
         } 
    });
});
```

However, it is recommended to always check the response to ensure there were no errors on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use dojo.xhrPost to submit your form